# Como distribuir o espaçamento das colunas de uma table responsiva igualmente?

Tags: css, front-end

Como posso distribuir o espaçamento das colunas igualmente de uma tabela usando CSS?

Ex:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Telefone</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `table-layout: fixed`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Telefone</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Acho que você consegue elaborar bem mais essa resposta colocando exemplos dela funcionando.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo na sua pergunta assim como na resposta.

Comment: Código de exemplo adicionado conforme solicitado.